# TypeError: Flask.__call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'

Tags: python, flask, pytest, wsgi

I created very simple Flask app, and it works in Flask dev mode just fine. But when I try to make tests for it I get this error:

> TypeError: Flask.**call**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'

Test code and error:

```
@pytest.fixture()
    def app():
>       app = main.app()
E       TypeError: Flask.__call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'environ' and 'start_response'

test_app.py:22: TypeError
```

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# /// = relative path, //// = absolute path
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

"""defining Model and Routes"""
```

folder structure:[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XNqS.png)

It is a problem with werkzeug I guess but I have no idea how to build it in standard Flask app instantiation.

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response

def application(environ, start_response):
    request = Request(environ)
    text = 'Hello %s!' % request.args.get('name', 'World')
    response = Response(text, mimetype='text/plain')
    return response(environ, start_response)
```

Comment: `main.app` is `Flask()`, so `main.app()` is `Flask()()`, that's for sure not what you want to do

Comment: Damn, it`s so obvious. Thank you!